# How do I import a custom dataset to TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

For my first assignment back at uni we have been given a dataset full of traffic signs organised into 43 folders of diffrent signs. I have no idea how to import the given Dataset into tensorflow, The files are .ppm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data into NumPy arrays then it's easy to use with Tensorflow Keras. `tf.keras.Model.fit()` and `tf.keas.Model.Predict()` can take Numpy arrays.

The .ppm format seems to be a very simple text format with one pixel value per line. So read each line into a list or directly into a NumPy array. You might need to skip the header lines while reading. See this question [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)